# What are all the formatting options for a Google+ post?

Tags: google-plus, formatting

What is the markup language for creating posts (and responding to posts)?

I know of the following ones:

- To make **text bold**, use stars around the text:  `*bold text*`
- To make *text italics*, use underscores: `_italic text_`

What else is there? Is there any way to insert bullet-lists? What about larger font sizes, etc?

Google+ is starting to become a blog of sorts, and having a fully featured markup language makes it very helpful for formulating useful and lengthy posts.

If no other native markups exist, is there any way to insert HTML?  Ultimately, what are the various freedoms we have in making and replying to posts to markup the text?

Comment: I wish they used Markdown. Sadly, they do not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately the markup for Google+ (and Google Talk by extension) is fairly limited.
You're missing:

- `-item-` for <s>strikethrough</s>
- `@name` or `+name` to tag someone.

> #### Drag and drop
>
> Add photos, videos, or links to your posts by dragging them directly to the share box. To add a link, drag the icon next to the URL from the address bar to the share box.
>
> #### Add style
>
> - Use underscores to italicize. _ italics_ → *italics*
> - Use asterisks to bold. * bold* → **bold**
> - Use hyphens to strikethrough. - strikethrough - → <del>strikethrough</del>
> - Compound formatting: *_ bold italic_* → ***bold italics*** (make sure the nesting mirrors on each end)
>
> #### Mention your friends
>
> Use + or @ to add someone to the conversation and link to their profile. +Natalie Villalobos or @Natalie Villalobos → +Natalie Villalobos learn more about mentioning people in posts.
>
> #### Post from the +1 button
>
> When you click the +1 button across the web, you'll have the opportunity to create a post with a link to the page you +1'd. Learn more about the +1 button.
>
> #### Share box chip colors
>
> In the sharebox, groups of people you share with appear as either a blue or green "chip", like "public" or "extended circles". When a chip is blue it means that you've selected the people with whom that content is being shared. For instance, your Family circle is blue because you decide who you place in that circle. When a chip is green, it means that it may contain people you haven't added to your circles. Your extended circles, for instance, appear as a green chip because some of these people likely aren't in your circles.

Reference: [Share a photo, video, link, or event](http://support.google.com/plus/answer/1053549?hl=en&topic=1257360&ctx=topic), section "Posting tips"

Comment: The original Markdown doesn't have [strikethrough](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) I placed the markup you need for strikethrough above.

Comment: Are there any others?  If this is all, Google+ could use some serious room to grow.  At a minimum, I'd like to be able to do some simple formatting like Bullet and Number lists.

Comment: Nope, that's it. Bold, italic, and strikethrough. http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1053549&topic=1257360&ctx=topic

Comment: Ohh, if Google+ or any other social networking starts accepting formatted text, then it would all look like a mess, not comments.

Comment: I'd really like to ad link text other than the url

Comment: Note that the G+ formatting doesn't always work, and sometimes it will just appear as `_italic_` instead of *`italic`*. Their parsing expression just isn't that great.

Answer (score 0):

I've used numbered and bullet pointed lists but I can no longer find the example page nor the one containing the original help. Vaguely remember the list was prefixed by square brackets and asterisks. e.g:

```
[*]Option 1
[*]Option 2
```

There's probably some sort of preceding tag, but cannot remember.
If anyone can provide more info with the help of this above memory jogger....

Answer (score 0):

To make bullets in Google+ Post:

1. press the "ALT"-button and HOLD IT WHILE TYPING
2. type the Code while holding the "ALT"-button,
3. release the "ALT"-button.

For instance, for "○" press ALT then press "**9**" on the Keypad before the entry. For Other types of bullets PRESS ALT and repeat the process by typing "8", "16" or "254", which will give these bullets ◘, ► and ■, respectively.

Answer (score -2):

To make a bullet point in a Google+ post: <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>.

Comment: Where can I find option 8?

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? the user is asking for all of the options available.

Comment: I think 'option' is that freeway-interchange key that Mac keyboards have, i.e. ⌘. I've found that in a lot of cases it's equivalent to Ctrl under Linux, but that doesn't seem to be working for me on Google Plus. But I literally only joined that site five minutes ago.

Comment: @MichaelScheper you're thinking of Command, which is the Mac's "Windows key" (aka "Super", in X11). The Option key is the Mac's Alt key. But this answer is merely sharing the [standard Mac keybinding](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Symbols-on-a-Mac#Using_the_Option_Key_Codes_sub) for the Bullet character (•), which is not in any way specific to Google+ and will only work on a Mac OS X system. (_My_ bullet was typed with `Compose+period+equals`, because I'm on Linux with xinput. But that information is equally useless to anyone on a different system.)

Comment: Yep—I use GNOME, and never without a mapping to the Compose key. Doesn't help format text in G+, but at least proper bullets are nicer than asterisks. ;-)